# Converter string no formato de array em um array e recuperar os valores

Tags: java, array

No banco de dados possuo um TEXT onde é salvo um array nesse formato:

```
[ 
    [ resumo: null ] 
    [ datainicio: 2015-09-17T00:00:00.000-0300 ] 
    [ datafim: 2015-09-22T00:00:00.000-0300 ] 
    [ equipamento: 3421 ] 
]
```

Preciso recuperar os valores da datainicio e datafim.
Como eu poderia fazer isso? Estava pesquisando sobre a função split do Java, mas não consegui utilizá-la da forma correta pra me trazer o resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "[[ resumo: null ] [ datainicio: 2015-09-17T00:00:00.000-0300 ] [ datafim: 2015-09-22T00:00:00.000-0300 ] [ equipamento: 3421 ]]"
                .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[["), "")    
                .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("]]"), "");

        String[] strArray = str.split(Pattern.quote("] ["));
        for (int i = 0; i menor strArray.length; i++)
            strArray[i] = strArray[i].replaceAll(Pattern.quote("] ["), "");

        for (String string : strArray)
            System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado Emir! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava! Feitos alguns tratamentos, ficou perfeito!

Answer (score 1):

Verifica se é o que tu pretendes:

(Este código não foi testado mas dá para teres ideia de como podes fazer)

```
String frase = "[ 
    [ resumo: null ] 
    [ datainicio: 2015-09-17T00:00:00.000-0300 ] 
    [ datafim: 2015-09-22T00:00:00.000-0300 ] 
    [ equipamento: 3421 ] 
]";  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("datainicio: (.*?) ]"); 
// para os outros casos deves de criar um Pattern idêntico  
// Pattern p = Pattern.compile("datafim: (.*?) ]"); 
// Pattern p = Pattern.compile("equipamento: (.*?) ]"); 

Matcher m = p.matcher(frase);  

while (m.find()) {  
    // chamada diferente:  
    System.out.println(m.group(1));  
}
```

[Vê aqui um pouco mais de informção sobre isto](http://www.guj.com.br/articles/1)

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Não conhecia esta forma! Consegui utilizá-la, mas caso eu venha a precisar recuperar outros campos, ou todos os campos, achei melhor utilizar a que o Emir Marques postou! De qualquer forma, obrigado! Abraço!